Definition of instantaneous volatility of simply-compounded forward rate
In section "3.6 Volatility Structures in One-Factor Short-Rate Models" in Brigo Mercurio, and in particular the subsection "Caplet Volatilities in the Market", the authors define the (percentage) instantaneous volatility at time $t$ of the simply-compounded forward rate $F(t; T, T+\tau)$ as:
$$\sigma(t; T,T+\tau)^2 = d \ln F(t; T, T+\tau) d \ln F(t; T, T+\tau)$$
Can you help me understand where this definition comes from? I would expect the instantaneous volatility to be given by the quadratic covariation $\sigma(t; T,T+\tau)^2 = dF(t; T, T+\tau) dF(t; T, T+\tau)$ and don't understand why the $\ln$ appears in the definition.

Log Normality of Rates: In many interest rate models, the forward rates are modeled in such a way that the log of the forward rate follows a process with constant or deterministic volatility. This is often because the volatility of interest rates is more stable when expressed in log terms.
Percentage Changes: The volatility of the log of a variable reflects the percentage volatility of the original variable.
Mathematical Convenience: In practice, financial models often use the logarithm to make the differential equations governing the rates more manageable.

Doesn't the fact that it is the percentage instantaneous volatility, rather than just the instantaneous volatility have to do with this?

$d(lnF)$ to first order is $dF/F$, the percentage volatility.

@NC520 yes, that's true .. I've edited the question.
